# Power BI Totals evaluation

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have the below table with many values that gives me a total PerecntageChange too.

```
Date      CheckType    State    Previous    Daily  PercentChange  KPI light
6/13/21    AM          AR         29489     33023    11.98%        Yellow
6/13/21    AM          KY         105496    104648   -.80%         Green
```

I need to create seperate KPI light metrics for totals. How can I do this?

`Measure`

```
Percentage change = 
VAR __BASELINE_VALUE = SUM('AutoDialerDaily'[PREV_CNT])
VAR __VALUE_TO_COMPARE = SUM('AutoDialerDaily'[CURR_CNT])
RETURN
IF(
    NOT ISBLANK(__VALUE_TO_COMPARE),
    DIVIDE(__VALUE_TO_COMPARE - __BASELINE_VALUE, __BASELINE_VALUE)
   )
```

`Column` Color Indicator that drives the KPI light (Conditional Formatting)

```
COLOR_IND_FORMAT = 
//IF(HASONEVALUE(AutoDialerDaily[State]),
SWITCH(
TRUE(),
AutoDialerDaily[Check type] = "STATE AM" && AutoDialerDaily[PRCNT_DIFF] >=16, "RED",
AutoDialerDaily[Check type] = "STATE AM" && AutoDialerDaily[PRCNT_DIFF] >=11 && AutoDialerDaily[PRCNT_DIFF] <=15 , "YELLOW",
AutoDialerDaily[Check type] = "STATE AM" && AutoDialerDaily[PRCNT_DIFF] <=10, "GREEN",
"BLACK")
```

I'm not sure what needs to happen here.

I want a separate set of "TOTAL Metrics" and to control the color. So, for example if I wanted to say if the Total is 2% that should display as a "BLUE" indicator

Answer (score 0):

You can create a measure as below:

```
COLOR_IND_FORMAT = 
SWITCH(
TRUE(),
VALUES('Table'[CheckType]) = "AM" && [Percentage change] >= 0.10, 1,
VALUES('Table'[CheckType]) = "AM" && [Percentage change] < 0.10, 2)
```

After this, select the "Conditional Formatting" option from the Format Pane. Select the "Percentage Change" column in the dropdown > Go to Icons > Advanced Controls

[image: Conditional formatting]

In the Advanced Controls box, you can format based on the measure you created. Please refer to the image below:

[image: Format rule]

Final Output:

[image: Output]

Hope this solves your problem.